# Same SQL query cannot run in SQL Server but works well in Azure SQL Transformation

Tags: sql, azure, transformation

I have written the attached query and in SQL server query process flow, **SELECT** is run almost last after **GROUP BY**.

I created a new column **AGE_GRP** in the **SELECT** using CASE-WHEN and used **GROUP BY AGE_GRP** in the same single-select query and it works even though GROUP BY is executed first then follow by SELECT and should throw an error because **AGE_GRP** is not found yet! In fact when i ran the same code in SQL Management Studio it gave an error 'Invalid Column name 'AGE_GRP'.

But in Azure ML Studio using SQL transformation it ran perfectly. Any ideas why?

[image]

Comment: Some databases extend the SQL standard to allow aliases in the `GROUP BY`.  Some follow the standard in this regard.

Answer (score 0):

Because they run in a different order,you can use sub query in sql-server then group it.

```sql
with cte as (
    select 18 Age, 'User01' Name union select 35 , 'User02' union select 75 , 'User02'
)
select 
    AGE_GRP,count(*) as NoTrans
from (
    select 
        (case  when Age < 30  then 'Young' when Age<50 then 'Middle' else 'Senior' end ) as AGE_GRP
        ,*
    from cte
) T
group by AGE_GRP
```

result :

> ```
> AGE_GRP | NoTrans
> :------ | ------:
> Middle  |       1
> Senior  |       1
> Young   |       1
> ```

[SQL Server 2017 | db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=b481576561e9150d942398c5e00c22c2)

Comment: Thanks. Yes I can used sub-query in sql server to solve the issue. Just puzzled whats the process flow for SQLite like since most traditional SQL servers run SELECT last

Comment: @Johnson Neo  most  process flow is `FROM > WHERE > GROUP BY > HAVING > SELECT > DISTINCT > UNION > ORDER BY`